# certificate authorities for a PKI

Tags: security, certificate, pki

Some people think the certificate authorities for a PKI should be the government, but others think certificate authorities should be private entities, such as banks, corporations, or schools. What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question multiple times! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272000/certificate-authorities-for-a-pki

Comment: This is not a stackoverflow question. Not sure about where to ask, but you can try the IT Security stackexchange [site](http://security.stackexchange.com/) or maybe it can fit in the scope of serverfault?

Comment: Flagged to move to security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MartinBuberl - would have been handier to migrate it to the security se rather than just close, as now @dwyane has asked the question again over there. 3 copies of the same question???

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would suggest this question is much more suited to http://security.stackexchange.com

It all comes down to who you trust. Some organisations will trust government, while some definitely won't. Some will trust a bank in this role, but would a competitor trust them? I have seen many banks set up their own PKIs or use a PKI vendor - and the physical security requirements around root CA generation and storage are very James Bond!

For your specific situation, look at your needs, trust requirements and risk. What PKI provider is most likely to match your needs? How is their disaster recovery and business coninuity plan structured - does this match your requirements? How do they prevent compromise of the root CA?

Answer (score 0):

The major problem with the Certificate Authority is that it should enforce the Trust of ALL the users.

Considering that the root certificate is the base of the trust, if you have a government here, its inherent authority over the resident of that country influence the trust of the certificate as a resident would not be able to argue he does not trust its country. The diplomacy take the relay for the trust outside the country.

Banks and corporation does not have this "automatic" trust. And by the way, the policies they may enforce on Certificate delivery and management may be a critical problem regarding the neutrality of the usages.

I hope it clarifies a bit your question.